# Bootstrap Carousel: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using bootstrap carousel and have come up with a function to generate the "item"s inside carousel-inner that works as expected.

When the user clicks one of many pictures on the page I show the carousel full-screen and populate it with other images from that folder (each image has its own folder with extra images related to it).

However, around 1 out of 5 times that I click on a picture I'm able to see the first item full-screen but the controls won't work (and I get the 'Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined' error on the console). The strange thing is that if I try to click that same picture again it will work fine.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row carousel-holder" id="fotenha2">
  <div class="col-md-12" id="carCol">
    <div id="banners" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" id="carCont" oncontextmenu="return false;">  
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#banners" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden:"true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#banners" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden:"true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>        
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function createCarousel(folder, items) {
  for (var i=1; i<=items; i++) {
    var content = document.getElementById('travelCont');
    var imageCont = document.getElementById('fotenha2');
    imageCont.style.display = "block";
    content.style.display = "none";
    var path = 'assets/travel/'+folder+'/000'+i+'.jpg';
    var item = document.createElement("DIV");
    var anchor = document.createElement("a");
    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.className="slide-image";
    img.src = path;
    anchor.appendChild(img);
    anchor.href = "";
    item.appendChild(anchor);
    item.className="item"; 
    if (i === 1) {
      item.className = "item active"; 
    }
  item.onclick="closeTravelArticle()";
  document.getElementById('carCont').appendChild(item);
  }
}
```

Any ideas of why this is happening will be very helpful.

PS: The solution for other questions like mine was to add "active" to the first item, which I'm already doing

Answer (score -2):

I suggest to use [AngularJS](https://github.com/angular/angular.js), they have a nice feature you can use called *ng-repeat*. All you need is an object with your data and the *ng-repeat* on the element you want to repeat.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []); 
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.items = {
      0 : {
        'id' : 1,
        'name' : 'Item 1'
      },
      1 : {
        'id' : 2,
        'name': 'Item 2'
      }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in items" id="{{ x.id }}">{{ x.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I suggest this based on my own experience. I am creating multiple projects with AngularJS now and I think it's one of the best frameworks there is. Also, for one of my projects I wanted to do the same as you, this worked excellent for me.